# Tableau table with more then 6 dimension columns

Tags: tableau-api

I have created a dashboard in Tableau with a 1 cross tab.
It contains 13 dimension columns and 14 measure columns.
in tableau desktop i can see 27 columns.
when i published it and checked the tableau online, i saw only 6 dimension columns.

is there any configuration that i'm missing?

thanks

Comment: Can you share some screenshots? This is something that makes little sense.

Comment: There are table layout options that affect this (see on desktop Analysis|Table Layout|Advanced menu). You can alter the maximum displayed column labels.

Comment: again, in the desktop i can see all the columns.
after i publish it the user who is looking at the web report can see only 6 of the 20+ measure columns